# Django - check cookies's "SameSite" attribute

Tags: python-3.x, django, cookies

In my Django application, I want to check if a specific cookies has "SameSite=None" or not.

I'm using this code to read the value of the cookies,

```
cookiesid = request.COOKIES["cookiesid"]
```

However, I don't know how to check "SameSite" attribute, seems there is no method to check it by request.COOKIES[""]

How can I check it?

I'm using Python 3.6.9 and Django 3.1

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've also been having issues with cross-domain Cookies recently, and I've tracked it down to Google Chrome gradually rolling out their security update that forces the **SameSite** attribute to **Lax** if it isn't set

**Lax** means that the Cookie is going to be blocked cross-domain by default on Google Chrome

Given that you're inspecting the Cookie's attributes in the code, I *think* that if the **SameSite** attribute isn't there, than you're not setting it and therefore Google Chrome is forcing the attribute to **Lax**

As you've stated you're using Django 3.1, the following four entries in your **settings.py** file might resolve your issue (as it did for me):

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
```

Good luck!

Comment: Links to docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-samesite and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-samesite

Answer (score 15):

Going a little bit deeper.

1. In production set:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
```

2. Do not set any of the above flags in development. It will say that cannot set the cookie with SameSite=None if the connection is NOT secure.

Also make sure that you have Django 3, in Django 2 there is a bug and it will output a ValueError.