# Recaptcha Samesite Cookie Error with Django 4.0.4

Tags: cookies, django-settings, samesite, recaptcha-v3

I have included Recaptcha v3 in my Django project but am faced with this error:

> "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by
> specifying its SameSite attribute"

I have tried following the answer in [Django - check cookies's "SameSite" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63576338/django-check-cookiess-samesite-attribute) and even referred to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-samesite), but I haven't been able to solve the problem.

First, I entered

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "random"
```

in settings.py to check if it would be recognized and cause an error and it did, so I changed it to

`CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "none"`

Then I received a more nuanced error -

> Mark cross-site cookies as Secure to allow setting them in cross-site contexts

Next, I added `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True` as per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-secure), but it achieves nothing. I still face the exact same error as with nothing at all. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the extent of my current understanding, it is not possible to have secure cookies on a non-https website.