# django_embed_video module throws error "e doesn't look like a module path"

Tags: python, django, youtube, embed

I have been 6 hours trying to figure out why doesn't the [`django_embed_video`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-embed-video) module work as supposed.
I followed the documentation. Created a model with `VideoEmbed` Field. Used it in `template.html`.

Added the following:

```py
EMBED_VIDEO_BACKENDS = (
    'embed_video.backends.YoutubeBackend',
)
```

to `settings.py`

All i am trying to achieve is to view a youtube video in my template, but i keep getting this error:

```py
detect_backend(str(backend_or_url))
File "project\venv\lib\site-packages\embed_video\backends.py", line 61, in detect_backend
backend = import_string(backend_name)
File "project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 27, in import_stringraise ImportError("%s doesn't look like a module path" % dotted_path) from err
ImportError: e doesn't look like a module path
```

**template.html**

```html
...
{% load static %}
{% load embed_video_tags %}
...
{% for tid, t in tests.items %}
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"> <!-- Bootstrap responsive layout -->
    {% video t.ytvideo.url %} <!-- iterate tests and get YT video of each test -->
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Theory: There is an error in detecting the backend, but I can't seem to get it!

If you have a diifferent way to achieve embedding youtube video in website, it would be appreciated. I have tried embedding yt video with just snippet code copied from yt website, but i faced tons of errors on the front-end regarding the CORS policies.

I installed django CORS module and allowed origin to all websites, yet kept facing cookie issues along with other CORS policies not working, or getting yt video blocked by the browser for cookie tracking issues. Further help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Now the page loads successfully but the video doesn't appear.

Console logs: `Some cookies are misusing the recommended “SameSite“ attribute`

I tried the following solution but didn't work:

```py
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Did you add `embed_video` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: @MahirLabibChowdhury Of course I did.

Comment: Most probably, this might be a typo. You might have used `EMBED_VIDEO_BACKENDS = ('embed_video.backends.YoutubeBackend')` instead of ***`EMBED_VIDEO_BACKENDS = ('embed_video.backends.YoutubeBackend',)`***.

Comment: @JPG This removed the error, though i have no idea where the typo is. Now the page loads successfully but the video doesn't appear, is it related to the fact i'm running the website locally? Though embedding youtube should work on localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: The typo is that you were missing a comma in the end to make it a `tuple`. Without it, `EMBED_VIDEO_BACKENDS` was only a `string`. Regarding your other issue, what kind of error message do you see?

Comment: Yes, django and a lot of other python related framework, does has this issue of ",", and everyone already explained this clearly. Ot

Comment: Did you include `'django.core.context_processors.request'` in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting (docs: https://django-embed-video.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#setup) ?

Comment: @Lich yes i did already. I just keep getting this error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id.` and similar CORS policies on the front-end console.

Comment: @YoussofH. If you're using localhost, then try to left `CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE` and  `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE ` to `'None'`. But set `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` and `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` to `False`. Also check related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67415924/6629686