# Django CSRF protection for cross site post requests

Tags: reactjs, django, axios, csrf

I am using react as frontend and using django for backend.
When I host both the frontend and backend on localhost, everything works fine and `X-CSRFTOKEN` is sent perfectly.

```
const instance = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    withXSRFToken: true,
    xsrfHeaderName : 'X-CSRFTOKEN',
    xsrfCookieName : 'csrftoken'
});
```

My DJango settings are (taken from this answer [Django - check cookies's "SameSite" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63576338/django-check-cookiess-samesite-attribute)):

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None"
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None"
```

but when my frontend (firebase )and backend(eks aws) are hosted on different subdomains, I receive a 403 Forbidden Error.
Edit:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:3000", "https://app.example.com"]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "https://app.example.com",
]
```

It should return a 201 ccreated response but instead it is returning a 403 error, `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`

Answer (score 0):

Add your domain name to `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://yourdomain.com']` in `settings.py`

Comment: I already have them in settings.py and also updated my question with details.

Answer (score 0):

The issue above was that when I inspected the cookies, the domain for csrf cookie was `backend.app.com`, and the frontend was hosted at `frontend.app.com.`
So I added this setting to my django settings module and everything worked fine:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".app.com"
```